# How to extend x-axis and y-axis and narrow the gap in ggthemes::theme_tufte()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following nibble:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> + ggplot2 2.2.1.9000        Date: 2017-06-23
#> + tibble  1.3.3                R: 3.3.2
#> + tidyr   0.6.3              GUI: X11
#> + readr   1.1.1           Locale: en_US.UTF-8
#> + purrr   0.2.2.2             TZ: Asia/Tokyo
#> + dplyr   0.7.0           
#> + stringr 1.2.0
#> Conflicts -----------------------------------------------------------------
#> * filter(),  from dplyr, masks stats::filter()
#> * lag(),     from dplyr, masks stats::lag()
tbl <- structure(list(sample = c("Fx", "Vx"), nof_degs = c(6038L, 
3606L)), .Names = c("sample", "nof_degs"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))

tbl
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   sample nof_degs
#>    <chr>    <int>
#> 1     Fx     6038
#> 2     Vx     3606
```

With the following code:

```r
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(tbl, aes(x=sample,y=nof_degs)) +
geom_histogram(position=position_dodge(0.01), colour="black", stat="identity", width=0.2) +
  geom_rangeframe() + 
  theme_tufte() +
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(7, "pt"))
```

As shown in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me know if this is close enough:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=sample,y=nof_degs)) +
  geom_histogram(position=position_dodge(0.01), colour="black",
                 stat="identity", width=0.8) +
  geom_rangeframe(y=c(0, max(df$nof_degs))) + 
  theme_tufte() +
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(5, "pt"))
```

[image]

Another option is with `aspect.ratio`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=sample,y=nof_degs)) +
  geom_histogram(position=position_dodge(2), colour="black",
                 stat="identity", width = 0.6) +
  geom_rangeframe(y=c(0, max(df$nof_degs))) + 
  theme_tufte() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 2) +
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(5, "pt"))
```

[image]

You can play around with `width` and `aspect.ratio` parameters to get a desired plot. For example `width = 0.8` and `aspect.ratio = 1.5`:

[image]

Comment: thanks a million. How can I make the bar thinner (25% thinner?)

Comment: decrease `width` to maybe `0.6`?

Comment: I tried ` geom_histogram(position=position_dodge(0.01), colour="black", stat="identity", width=0.2)`, with your code. It increases the gap again.Which I tried to avoid.

Comment: Just set it to `0,5`. It should be fine. And play around that value.

Comment: Tried that too. Still big gaps.